# Lesshat and Brunch

Tags: brunch, lesshat

I'd like to make the popular LESS library LessHat available to my Brunch template but I want it done in a way that I can:

- Take advantage of the Bower integration so I always have the latest
- Rather than having the library transpiled to CSS I want the LESS to be made available to my own custom LESS files

Is this possible? A step too far? Obviously, it's not hard to put the static LESS file into my `app/stylesheets` directory but this makes the linking static and I don't get the Bower integration which would be pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

Just link to the lesshat-file in your less files. This way you can use lesshat-functions and still update lesshat with bower.

For example

@import 'bower_components/lesshat/build/lesshat-prefixed.less';

if you have styles.less in your project root folder.